# BIRT Viewer randomly fails to open report

Tags: birt

I'm running birt 3.7.2 using the Birt Web Viewer and have recently been encountering an error when opening my reports / changing the report parameters.

The error is as follows:

> An error occurred while getting report parameters. The specified report: /$$$Transient/acfile20.rptdocument was not found. The report may have expired or may not have been generated.

It also throws a "Get page count failed." error message too. I'm sure it's related to the message above.

It's not happening on all of the different instances of BIRT that I'm using. I've checked what I think is the Transient folder and it is not generating these files, yet sometimes, if I refresh the report, it will run.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using either a dynamic parameter or computed column, try disabling either.  For example if there is a dynamic parameter make it static, if there is a computed column try removing it.